# ARRAYFORMULA - get value after certain date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm building a sheets with the following pages:

- Records
- Team

Records Page:

| Date | Time | Where | User | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 01:40 | Warehouse | Mike Silva | 14,00$ |
| 04/01/2022 | 07:40 | Main Office | Mike Silva | 15,00$ |

Team Page:

| Date | User | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Mike Silva | 14,00$ |
| 03/01/2022 | Mike Silva | 15,00$ |

Up until the 3rd of January Mike had a pay of 14,00$ and from the 3rd onwards is pay was bumped to 15$. I've used INDEX/MATCH to get the pay within the correct date, but I can't get it into a ArrayFormula to auto update all cells.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a copy of your spreadsheet, as well as the formula you currently have?

Comment: Hi @lamblichus, I think I solved my question. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72144447/19051791

Would love to get your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

each character has its own `CHAR` code:

[image]

so first we convert names into numbers:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A4, "(?:)(.)", "$1 "), " "), 
 {CHAR(ROW(44:122)),SEQUENCE(79)}, 2, 0))),,9^9)), " ", ))
```

[image]

and next, we sum it and just add date and run approximate vlookup:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 MMULT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(D1:D, D1:D<>""), 
 "(?:)(.)", "$1×"), "×"), {CHAR(ROW(44:122)), SEQUENCE(79)}, 2, 0))*1, 
 SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(D1:D)), 1, 1, 1))*A1:A, {
 MMULT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(H2:H, H2:H<>""), 
 "(?:)(.)", "$1×"), "×"), {CHAR(ROW(44:122)), SEQUENCE(79)}, 2, 0))*1,
 SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(H2:H)), 1, 1, 1))*G2:G, I2:I}, 2, 1)))
```

[image]

---

### update

or just:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(D1:D&A1:A, SORT({H2:H&G2:G, I2:I}), 2, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello player0, I appreciate your answer but I think I found a simplified answer... Would like your input, if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72144447/19051791

Comment: @diogogpinto yes, that will work too, but keep in mind that 2nd argument of vlookup should be sorted

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer after some trial/error.

On team page I created a helper column (User + Date):

| Date | Helper | User | Pay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | Mike Silva|44562 | 14,00$ | Mike Silva |
| 03/01/2022 | Mike Silva|44564 | 15,00$ | Mike Silva |

Then, i just:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(PROCV(USER&"|"&DATE;Team!B2:D;3;TRUE))
```

Thank you so much for your help!